# Several enemy movements in game development

Tags: java, design-patterns, libgdx

I am writing a simple shoot'em up game in Java using LibGDX as the main library. I would like that any enemy in the game could perform any sort of movement, regardless their type. The problem arises when trying to isolate the logic of the movements an AI from each Enemy class.

A more graphic example:

1. Mov A: Linear, from top to bottom.
2. Mov B: Chase player character
3. Mov C: Show up, shoot and flee.

Enemies:

1. Spider. Perform Mov A
2. Another spider. Perform Mov B
3. To sum up: Being able to assign moves regardless the enemy.

What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an entity system library like https://github.com/libgdx/ashley or https://github.com/junkdog/artemis-odb.

You would then create systems:

1. `LinearTopBottomMovementSystem`
2. `ChasePlayerMovementSystem`
3. `ShowUpSystem`
4. `ShootSystem` (you probably also want an`BulletMovementSystem`)
5. `FleeSystem`

Then create components:

1. `LinearTopBottomMovementComponent`
2. `ChasePlayerMovementComponent`
3. `ShowUpComponent`
4. `ShootComponent`
5. `FleeComponent`

When creating enemies (entities) you create:

1. Spider entity with `LinearTopBottomMovementComponent`
2. Another spider entity with `ChasePlayerMovementComponent`
3. Spider entity with `ShowUpComponent`
4. After `ShowUpComponent` is handled (by the `ShowUpSystem`), remove this component and add `ShootComponent`
5. After `ShootComponent` is handled (by the `ShootSystem`), remove this component and add `FleeComponent`

This allows you to create enemies with all possible component combinations and you can add multiple components to one entity.

If you decide to add circle movement and permanent fire enemy. Just create `CircleMovementComponent` and `PermanentFireComponent` and corresponding systems.

Comment: Despite the fact that the other answers are rather handy, I am accepting this one because of the **ECS** pattern - which I am already using through ashley, as I wisely mentioned - Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Declare an abstract class `MoveType` and an abstract class `Monster`.

Give `Monster` method `setPosition(int x, int y)`. Give `MoveType` a field that holds a variable of type `Monster`. Make `MoveType` have abstract methods for determining how and where to move based on current position, player position, etc. `Monster` can have a method called `move()` which calls the abstract methods and then calls `Monster.setPosition()` to implement the chosen move.

Then declare implementations of `MoveType` like `MoveA`, `MoveB`, etc. Those should use their own internal logic to determine how to move.

Make sure you allow `Monster` to have some method which allows you to set the `Monster`'s `MoveType`.

This approach gives you the flexibility to add more monsters or move types without modifying the underlying structure. All you need to do is define a new `MoveType`, implement the logic for where to move, and pass an instance of the new `MoveType` to an instance of `Monster`. You could even change the move type of a `Monster` in the middle of the game based on some condition (maybe when it gets close enough to the player).

Untested example below, but the idea should be solid:

```
public abstract class Monster {
 public int xPosition;
 public int yPosition;

 public MoveType move;

 public Monster(int x, int y, MoveType move) {
  xPosition = x;
  yPosition = y;
  this.move = move;
 }

 public void setPosition(int x, int y) {
  xPosition = x;
  yPosition = y;
 }

 public void move() {
  setPosition(move.determineXMove(), move.determineYMove());
 }
}
```

-

```
public abstract class MoveType {
 public Monster monster;

 public MoveType(Monster monster) {
  this.monster = monster;
 }

 public abstract void determineXMove();
 public abstract void determineYMove();
}
```

-

```
public class MoveLeft extends MoveType() {
 @Override
 public void determineXMove() {
  return monster.xPosition - 1;
 }

 @Override
 public void determineYMove() {
  return monster.yPosition;
 }
}
```

Using the above you would declare a monster, passing it a new starting position and `MoveLeft` object. Then you would continuously call its `move()` method within your game loop.